# Vector of structs in a card game not displaying card after, not sure if deck was even created

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm making a basic card game in c++ and I know my cards are getting created, I just don't know if they're even being put into the vector.

I've tried using functions to pass back the information, I've tested it out without shuffling to see if it at least detects the correct guesses.

```
struct card
{
   string cardFace, cardSuit;
};


int main()
{

    vector<card> deck;
    card currentCard;
    string input;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        string suits[4] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs" };

        for (int j = 1; j < 13; j++)//13 cards per suit
        {
            card a;

            if (j == 1)
                a.cardFace = "Ace";

            if (j == 11)
                a.cardFace = "Jack";

            if (j == 12)
                a.cardFace = "Queen";

            if (j == 13)
                a.cardFace = "King";

            else
                a.cardFace = to_string(j);

            a.cardSuit = suits[i];
            deck.push_back(a);
        }
    }

    random_shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end());

    currentCard.cardFace = deck[0].cardFace;
    currentCard.cardSuit = deck[0].cardSuit;

    if(input == currentCard.cardFace)
    cout << currentCard.cardFace << " is the right answer!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output to be: Jack is the right answer!
but I got:   is the right answer!

Comment: I don't see the definition of `input` in your posted code.

Comment: Please edit your post with the results from your debugging session.

Comment: You should move `string suits` definition to before the `for` loop or make it `static`.  It doesn't need to be created each iteration.  Also, make it `const` if the array isn't modified.

Comment: You can simplify your program by using `currentCard = deck[0];`.  The compiler should emit code to copy each member; if not, add an assignment operator to your structure.

Comment: The only output I see in your code is inside of an `if` that will always be false. [Here is your code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mxS50A9ioSkY4RhD) modified a bit and with the whole deck displayed after construction.

Comment: Note that `a.cardFace` is always `to_string(j)` — the `else` is in relation to the last `if` only, and `j` is never 13.

Comment: Why don't you print the vector elements and see what's there?

Answer (score 2):

I tried that variation of your program on [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/VGTxHG) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct card
{
   string cardFace, cardSuit;
};


int main()
{
    vector<card> deck;
    card currentCard;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        string suits[4] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs" };

        for (int j = 1; j < 13; j++)//13 cards per suit
        {
            card a;

            if (j == 1)
                a.cardFace = "Ace";

            if (j == 11)
                a.cardFace = "Jack";

            if (j == 12)
                a.cardFace = "Queen";

            if (j == 13)
                a.cardFace = "King";

            else
                a.cardFace = to_string(j);

            a.cardSuit = suits[i];
            deck.push_back(a);
        }
    }

    random_shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end());

    currentCard.cardFace = deck[0].cardFace;
    currentCard.cardSuit = deck[0].cardSuit;

    cout << currentCard.cardFace << " " << currentCard.cardSuit << " is the right answer!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And it worked as expected.

Comment: It might just be my compiler, I'll test it out on others and see if it's only my compiler

Comment: @L.Nguyen You could try to change your structure definition for `typedef struct scard { string cardFace, cardSuit; } card;`.

Comment: @MartinVéronneau That's a C convention which is completely unnecessary in C++.

Comment: @MartinVéronneau yeah, don't do that in C++

Comment: I know, but depending on the compiler and/or the age of said compiler (to which the OP didn't provide details), that might be the problem. I would know ; I'm using a compiler from 1986 and it has all sort of quirks. I can't count how many time I wrote completely unnecessary code just to please that god-forsaken compiler. I was just offering a practical suggestion that might have helped find the culprit. Just to be clear, that's not an actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only output I see in your program is guarded by an if that will always be false because you never set `input`. It seems you are interested in validating that your deck was constructed successfully. To do that, add this at the bottom of your `main` [live example here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mxS50A9ioSkY4RhD)

```
for (auto& c : deck) {
    std::cout << c.cardFace << " " << c.cardSuit << '\n';
}
```

The above displays all of the cards in your `deck`. Though there are [many more changes](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UN9ulN4A0GiNYxU2) I'd recommend.